# What are the restrictions on what can and cannot be done in a a service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Further to [Can I http poll or use socket.io from a Service Worker on Safari iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550581/can-i-http-poll-or-use-socket-io-from-a-service-worker-on-safari-ios/61560232#61560232) what is the list of what can and cannot be done in a service worker? The answer referenced above says "You cannot ... have an open connection of any sort to your server" which makes sense, but where is that fact documented and how is the restriction enforced?

For example, are certain browser APIs unavailable to Service Workers? or is there an execution quota which prevents a long running process?

Eg. if my service worker has ...
`setInterval (()=>{console.log('foo'), 1000})` 
... will it throw an exception?, will it run and then fail? is the behaviour browser dependent?

Comment: Browser-dependent for sure, and also likely dependent on system resources.  I've never seen a definitively list of current behaviors, but have witnessed a whole smattering of things.  In Chrome on desktop, for example, I've had service workers be killed off in seconds, and some lasting hours.

Comment: Although I'd love to see a list where someone lists every limitation they've seen or even better tested for already, caniuse style, I think it's pretty unrealistic to expect one.  Someone please post a list if you have one or just resources where people are already working on lists.

Answer (score 4):

Service Workers are only supposed to process attached events.
And those are to be registered by some script from the outside.
Even delaying the execution is not supported in some cases on Safari - Event.waitUntil(promise).

Once your event queue is empty, your user agent is supposed to decide wether it kills of the service. There is no guarantee that anything from then on is going to get executed.

Comment: Are you saying that any async operation is not guaranteed to succeed because it executes outside the event loop?

Comment: no, async calls with promises are fine. and it depends on the browser - reinstating a new async call may not be. also safari doesnt even support waituntil.

Comment: so, for example, if an event handler in the SW calls `setTimeout(()=>{console.log('foo')}, 1000)`, that's OK provided it's wrapped in a Promise? How about `setTimeout(()=>{console.log('foo')}, 1000*60*60)` or `setInterval(()=>{console.log('foo')}, 1000)`?

NB. I'm not necessarily looking to do either of these things. My question is to understand where the list of what works and what doesn't is defined.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty because otherwise it would be forfeit. However I haven't accepted the answer because I am hoping for an authoritative source which states what will and will not work, rather than what they are supposed to or not supposed to be used for.

Comment: that is the problem, it seems like its supposed to be used for almost everything and nothing at the same time. getting informed through desktop notifications on changes, blockchain and so on. but those get initiated by events. and its rather something to explore atm than something that has go to use-cases. so, every user-agent decides for itself i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

A [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) is not just another thread but a very specific kind of thread. As in it is meant to intercept network and resource fetch requests and do something with it. In its most basic form, it caches if the network is not available, but it can also return a different resource than what was requested, an older version or a placeholder etc.

> Eg. if my service worker has ... `setInterval (()=>{console.log('foo'),
>   1000})` ... will it throw an exception? will it run and then fail? is
>   the behaviour browser dependent?

It will likely work. However, there is very little point of doing this since you neither have any DOM access nor can you directly interact with the user. At most, you can print out errors and warnings though I don't know what warning would require interval polling.

From the question, it sounds you are trying to accomplish some background work without blocking the main thread. In which case, the more generic type (the [Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker)) is your friend.